# Slow data loading to MongoDB from pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pandas, performance

I have 2 large csv files that need to be loaded to Mongo collections. Firstly, I read the data into pandas Dataframe, do some preprocessing and after that insert the resulting dict into Mongo collection. The problem is that the performance is very slow, because it's executed sequentially and loading data to second collection should be done after first collection is already filled (to update the rows with foreign keys). How can I speed up the process of loading?

```
import pymongo
import config
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from config import logger


client = pymongo.MongoClient(config.IP)
try:
    client.server_info()
except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError as e:
    logger.error("Unable to connect to %s. Error: %s" % (config.IP, e))
    client = None

# connect to database (or create if not exists)
mydb = client[config.DB_NAME]

# connect to collections (or create if not exists)
movie_collection = mydb[config.DB_MOVIE_COLLECTION]
actors_collection = mydb[config.DB_ACTOR_COLLECTION]


def read_data(file):
    '''
    returns Dataframe with read csv data
    '''
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t')
    df.replace('\\N', np.nan, inplace=True)
    return df


def insert_to_collection(collection, data):
    collection.insert(data)


def fill_movie_data():
    '''
    iterates over movie Dataframe
    process values and creates dict structure
    with specific attributes to insert into MongoDB movie collection
    '''


    # load data to pandas Dataframe
    logger.info("Reading movie data to Dataframe")
    data = read_data('datasets/title.basics.tsv')

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        result_dict = {}

        id_ = row['tconst']
        title = row['primaryTitle']

        # check value of movie year (if not NaN)
        if not pd.isnull(row['endYear']) and not pd.isnull(row['startYear']):
            year = list([row['startYear'], row['endYear']])
        elif not pd.isnull(row['startYear']):
            year = int(row['startYear'])
        else:
            year = None

        # check value of movie duration (if not NaN)
        if not pd.isnull(row['runtimeMinutes']):
            try:
                duration = int(row['runtimeMinutes'])
            except ValueError:
                duration = None
        else:
            duration = None

        # check value of genres (if not NaN)
        if not pd.isnull(row['genres']):
            genres = row['genres'].split(',')
        else:
            genres = None

        result_dict['_id'] = id_
        result_dict['primary_title'] = title

        # if both years have values
        if isinstance(year, list):
            result_dict['year_start'] = int(year[0])
            result_dict['year_end'] = int(year[1])

        # if start_year has value
        elif year:
            result_dict['year'] = year

        if duration:
            result_dict['duration'] = duration

        if genres:
            result_dict['genres'] = genres

        insert_to_collection(movie_collection, result_dict)



def fill_actors_data():
    '''
    iterates over actors Dataframe
    process values, creates dict structure
    with new fields to insert into MongoDB actors collection
    '''


    logger.info("Inserting data to actors collection")
    # load data to pandas Dataframe
    logger.info("Reading actors data to Dataframe")
    data = read_data('datasets/name.basics.tsv')

    logger.info("Inserting data to actors collection")
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        result_dict = {}

        id_ = row['nconst']
        name = row['primaryName']

        # if no birth year and death year value
        if pd.isnull(row['birthYear']):
            yob = None
            alive = False
        # if both birth and death year have value
        elif not pd.isnull(row['birthYear']) and not pd.isnull(row['deathYear']):
            yob = int(row['birthYear'])
            death = int(row['deathYear'])
            age = death - yob
            alive = False
        # if only birth year has value
        else:
            yob = int(row['birthYear'])
            current_year = datetime.now().year
            age = current_year - yob
            alive = True

        if not pd.isnull(row['knownForTitles']):
            movies = row['knownForTitles'].split(',')

        result_dict['_id'] = id_
        result_dict['name'] = name
        result_dict['yob'] = yob
        result_dict['alive'] = alive
        result_dict['age'] = age
        result_dict['movies'] = movies

        insert_to_collection(actors_collection, result_dict)

        # update movie documents with list of actors ids
        movie_collection.update_many({"_id": {"$in": movies}}, {"$push": { "people": id_}})



# if collections are empty, fill it with data
if movie_collection.count() == 0:
    fill_movie_data()

if actors_collection.count() == 0:
    fill_actors_data()
```

Comment: Try pd.read_csv(file,chunksize=1000, sep='\t').

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Instead of inserting one record at a time, [insert in bulk](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#bulk-inserts).

## `insert_many`

At the moment you have:

```
def insert_to_collection(collection: pymongo.collection.Collection, data: dict):
    collection.insert(data)
```

you are using `insert()` which is deprecated, by the way.

What you want to have is:

```
def insert_to_collection(collection: pymongo.collection.Collection, data: list):
    collection.insert_many(data)
```

So in your two functions: `fill_movie_data` and `fill_actors_data`, instead of calling `insert_to_collection()` all the time in the loop, you can call it once in a while and insert in bulk.

## Code

Below is the code you posted with a few modifications:

Add a `max_bulk_size` which the larger the better for your speed, just make sure it doesn't exceed your RAM.

```
max_bulk_size = 500
```

Add a `results_list` and append `result_dict` to it. Once the size of the list reaches the `max_bulk_size`, save it and empty the list.

```
def fill_movie_data():
    '''
    iterates over movie Dataframe
    process values and creates dict structure
    with specific attributes to insert into MongoDB movie collection
    '''


    # load data to pandas Dataframe
    logger.info("Reading movie data to Dataframe")
    data = read_data('datasets/title.basics.tsv')

    results_list = []

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        result_dict = {}

        id_ = row['tconst']
        title = row['primaryTitle']

        # check value of movie year (if not NaN)
        if not pd.isnull(row['endYear']) and not pd.isnull(row['startYear']):
            year = list([row['startYear'], row['endYear']])
        elif not pd.isnull(row['startYear']):
            year = int(row['startYear'])
        else:
            year = None

        # check value of movie duration (if not NaN)
        if not pd.isnull(row['runtimeMinutes']):
            try:
                duration = int(row['runtimeMinutes'])
            except ValueError:
                duration = None
        else:
            duration = None

        # check value of genres (if not NaN)
        if not pd.isnull(row['genres']):
            genres = row['genres'].split(',')
        else:
            genres = None

        result_dict['_id'] = id_
        result_dict['primary_title'] = title

        # if both years have values
        if isinstance(year, list):
            result_dict['year_start'] = int(year[0])
            result_dict['year_end'] = int(year[1])

        # if start_year has value
        elif year:
            result_dict['year'] = year

        if duration:
            result_dict['duration'] = duration

        if genres:
            result_dict['genres'] = genres

        results_list.append(result_dict)

        if len(results_list) > max_bulk_size:
            insert_to_collection(movie_collection, results_list)
            results_list = []
```

Same with your other loop.

```
def fill_actors_data():
    '''
    iterates over actors Dataframe
    process values, creates dict structure
    with new fields to insert into MongoDB actors collection
    '''


    logger.info("Inserting data to actors collection")
    # load data to pandas Dataframe
    logger.info("Reading actors data to Dataframe")
    data = read_data('datasets/name.basics.tsv')

    logger.info("Inserting data to actors collection")

    results_list = []

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        result_dict = {}

        id_ = row['nconst']
        name = row['primaryName']

        # if no birth year and death year value
        if pd.isnull(row['birthYear']):
            yob = None
            alive = False
        # if both birth and death year have value
        elif not pd.isnull(row['birthYear']) and not pd.isnull(row['deathYear']):
            yob = int(row['birthYear'])
            death = int(row['deathYear'])
            age = death - yob
            alive = False
        # if only birth year has value
        else:
            yob = int(row['birthYear'])
            current_year = datetime.now().year
            age = current_year - yob
            alive = True

        if not pd.isnull(row['knownForTitles']):
            movies = row['knownForTitles'].split(',')

        result_dict['_id'] = id_
        result_dict['name'] = name
        result_dict['yob'] = yob
        result_dict['alive'] = alive
        result_dict['age'] = age
        result_dict['movies'] = movies

        results_list.append(result_dict)

        if len(results_list) > max_bulk_size:
            insert_to_collection(actors_collection, results_list)
            results_list = []

        # update movie documents with list of actors ids
        movie_collection.update_many({"_id": {"$in": movies}}, {"$push": { "people": id_}})
```